# issue of ground filter in octomap_server

Tags: ros, filter, pcl, octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am testing the octomap_server
and I used the sample data from http://vimeo.com/1451349?pg=embed&sec=1451349, which is a pcap file collected from a velodyne 64 laser.

Judged from the video and the pointcloud display in rviz, the ground surface is obviously contained in the data set. In my testing, the base_frame_id is set to "base_footprint" which is exactly located at the ground surface; filter_ground is also set to "true". But the generated octomap never filters the ground... and this is the output from the node.

[INFO] [1329732147.087671086] class OctomapServer starts

[INFO] [1329732147.103789973] filter_ground 1

[WARN][1329732208.260183596] No plane found in cloud.

[WARN][1329732208.260282727] No ground plane found in scan

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28117/issue-of-ground-filter-in-octomap_server/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, Hornung,

After some debugging, I found the reason for the above filtering issue.

Check the sequence of the following lines in the function OctomapServer::insertCloudCallback of OctomapServer.cpp,

```
pass.setInputCloud(pc.makeShared());
......

pcl::transformPointCloud(pc, pc, sensorToBase);
pass.filter(pc);
filterGroundPlane(pc, pc_ground, pc_nonground);
......
```

Since the inputcloud for pass is allocated at the very beginning, so the actual "pc" passed to filterGroundPlane is the old one before transformPointCloud.

So I moved pass.setInputCloud(pc.makeShared()) to right after the line of transformPointCloud, and the ground filtering now works as expected.

The same change should also apply to the case when m_filterGroundPlane=false.

regards

---

Originally posted by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) with karma: 393 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-02-24**:
Thanks a lot! That must have sneaked in during some recent refactoring. I had assumed makeShared simply returns a Ptr to the cloud, while the docs clearly state: "Copy the cloud to the heap and return a smart pointer. [...] The changes of the returned cloud are not mirrored back to this one"

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-02-24**:
Fixed in trunk of octomap_mapping